# Correctly show 3d model on marker using Kudan AR SDK for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan

I try build app on Kudan platform. I am using Unity 3d and the last version of Kudan SDK. I used Marker tracking but I don't how to set correct position to 3d model which I want to show on marker. When I build app and use marker for show 3d model. 3d model is still moves and floats above or below the marker. Is it possible set marker and 3d model in Unity to the same level? Is is possible show marker in Unity scene-mode?